# Absolute path information is required error

Tags: c#

Here is my code:

```
FtpConnection ftp = new FtpConnection(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["server"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["user"], ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["password"]);
ftp.Open();
ftp.Login();
FtpFileInfo[] files = null;
if (ftp.DirectoryExists(some_name))
{
    ftp.SetCurrentDirectory(some_name);
    files = ftp.GetFiles("*.xlsx");
    string fileName = files[0].Name;
}
return;
```

Everything works well. The fileName variable has the correct name.
However I get error code 500 even though nothing crashed. The error says: Absolute path information is required.

What does this mean? How to fix it?

When I debugged I noticed that when I expand the properties of files, there is one property Exists, which has the exact same error.

Comment: What is the value of `some_name`?

Comment: @MatthewWatson It's value is '/fold'. In my ftp server I have another folder named 'fold' and in it are the files I need.

Comment: You could try using Path.GetFullPath() to convert some_name (or some other filename). I'm just trying to think of something to try based on the error message.

Comment: Can't find this class anywhere in net libraries. Are you using a thirdy party assembly?

Comment: @Steve Yes, I'm using ftplib.

Comment: Why is everyone using `ConfigurationManager` instead of `Properties.Settings.Default` as I do? Just out of interest...

Comment: @MatthewWatson With that it searches for this path: C:/fold and it goes to catch.

Answer (score -1):

See the below link(s)

Although they are not the exact same issue - it should point you in the right direction?

[Link1](http://p2p.wrox.com/net-framework-2-0/44150-exception-absolute-path-information-required.html)

[Link2](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/csharpide/thread/d8b66574-9b1c-480d-a5f7-260aa5fde5ad/)

Hope this helps

Comment: They don't have anything to do with my question.